InvalidUseOfMatchersException when stubbing
I'm getting mockito exception when doing the stubbing:
@Mock
RetryTemplate retryTemplate;

@Test
public void testSubmitCreditTransaction() {
    when(retryTemplate.execute(any())).thenAnswer(invocation -> {             // line 224
        RetryCallback retry = invocation.getArgument(0);
        return retry.doWithRetry(null);
    });

    ...
}

the exception is:
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.InvalidUseOfMatchersException: 
Invalid use of argument matchers!
3 matchers expected, 1 recorded:
-> at     com.abc.rewards.accumulation.service.RewardsAccumulationServiceTest.testSubmitCreditTransaction(RewardsAccumulationServiceTest.java:224)

This exception may occur if matchers are combined with raw values:
    //incorrect:
    someMethod(any(), "raw String");
When using matchers, all arguments have to be provided by matchers.
For example:
    //correct:
    someMethod(any(), eq("String by matcher"));

For more info see javadoc for Matchers class.

    at     app//org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate.execute(RetryTemplate.java:211)
...

there is only one parameter to execute() and matcher is used. no raw values were used. no syntax errors.
I replaced any() with any(RetryCallback.class). the error persisted.
what did I get wrong?

Please post entire stack trace

The problem is that you are attempting to mock a final method. You can't do that. Edit: turns out you can in recent versions of Mockito, for some reason it's not working here.
According to the source, this is the method you are trying to stub:
    @Override
    public final <T, E extends Throwable> T execute(RetryCallback<T, E> retryCallback) throws E {
        return doExecute(retryCallback, null, null);
    }

When calling a mock method, Mockito notes that this method was called, but unless you've already told it how to react to a call to this method, it does nothing further. In particular, it won't call the overridden method. When you call .thenAnswer on what when(...) returns, Mockito can link up the mock method you called with the answer to use when the method gets called in your test.
However, it seems that in your setup, Mockito isn't mocking the final .execute(...) method. When you call execute(...) on your mock RetryTemplate, the real .execute(...) method in the source-code above looks to be executing. This calls doExecute (which will be a mock method) with three parameters. Only one of these parameters uses a matcher, the other two are null, and this explains the error you are getting.
I note that RetryTemplate implements the interface RetryOperations. Is it possible to use that interface in your code instead of RetryTemplate?

Mockito used to be unable to mock final methods. But now it can. See https://www.baeldung.com/mockito-final and https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/mock-mockfinal-classes-finally-yasin-bhojawala/ and https://www.infoq.com/news/2023/01/mockito-5/ - and the official doc: https://javadoc.io/doc/org.mockito/mockito-core/latest/org/mockito/Mockito.html#39

@k314159: you're right. the code worked fine before I update the dependencies in build.gradle. before I was using mockito-core:3.11.2 and mockito-inline3.11.2. I'm trying to rollback the change but I got Junit problem: "Cannot resolve symbol 'Before'"

@techie11 it seems you've changed your dependencies to much older versions. @before was a JUnit 4 annotation but nowadays you should be using JUnit 5. Similarly, if you use a recent version of Mockito, you should be able to do what you want.

the issue has been resolved by after rolled back to:
testImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-core:3.11.2'
testImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-inline:3.11.2'
testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.7.2'
testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.7.2'
testImplementation 'org.junit.vintage:junit-vintage-engine:5.7.2'

@k314159: thanks, I did not know that. It would have been useful for the OP to add to their question that "the code worked fine before I update the dependencies", as per their comment above. Still, my answer did at least offer an explanation of why Mockito was reporting "3 matchers expected, 1 recorded": for some reason the mocking of the final method appeared not to be working and the 'real' final method was still being called.

The problem arises from overloaded methods.
RetryTemplate#execute() can be called with different parameters. You can find the details here.
Using Mockito you can make your overloaded method call as follows:
doAnswer(invocation -> {
    RetryCallback retry = invocation.getArgument(0);
    return retry.doWithRetry(null);
}).when(retryTemplate).execute(any());

I hope this helps you.

the issue was resolved after rollback test dependencies to:
testImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-core:3.11.2'
testImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-inline:3.11.2'
testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.7.2'
testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.7.2'
testImplementation 'org.junit.vintage:junit-vintage-engine:5.7.2'

mockito-inline is the key because it supports mocking final methods

Mockito switched to inline by default after version 5.0, so in theory you should be able to use the latest (org.mockito:mockito-core:5.12.0) without mockito-inline.
